# Passing char ** to a function expecting const char **

Tags: c, pointers, constants

As per this [question, from c-faq.com](http://c-faq.com/ansi/constmismatch.html), it's not possible to assign a `char **` to a `const char **` without a cast. The explanation given at the link is perfectly reasonable and easy to understand. Indeed, doing it would violate the promise not to modify the pointed data.

I, cannot understand *Why is it illegal to pass it to a funcion*?

I can't see why this

```
void 
function(const char **pointer)
{
    // Prevent modifying pointer
}

int
main(void)
{
    char **pointer;
    // Initialize pointer
    function(pointer);
    return 0;
}
```

is not possible either.

Comment: I think you can? http://ideone.com/L9dgkk

Comment: You answered your own question, I don't understand what are you asking here.

Comment: @Ben No you cant: https://ideone.com/pNfgvY

Comment: @2501 Ok, different compiler flags.

Comment: @Ben Same compiler, just not ignoring the errors. It doesn't matter really , C says it is not defined.

Comment: @2501 Precisely why, the example you linked is invalid. If there is no apparent danger in doing it.

Comment: *Assigning a char ** to a const char ** (as in line 3, and in the original question) is not immediately dangerous. But it sets up a situation in which p2's promise--that the ultimately-pointed-to value won't be modified--cannot be kept.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It isn't allowed for the same reason assigning isn't allowed. To adapt the example from your link:

```
const char c = 'x';
void function(const char **p2)
{
    *p2 = &c;
}
int main() {
    char *p1;
    function(&p1); //*********
    *p1 = 'X';  
}
```

If the marked line was allowed, it would allow you to change the value of the constant variable `c`.

Comment: I didn't even think of global variables because I rarely use them, but I see the point.

Comment: I've read something similar before asking, they all treated the assignment only so that's why I asked. But you are 100% right. Also, the cast isn't so annoying, but it's still a shame that it doesn't work.

Comment: Oh, and changing the signature to `const char *const *const list` and casting to silence the warning I think is a good solution. I really want my funcion to read and only read from the passed parameter, I don't want it to alter it in any way at all.